# clear and accurate S.E. website navigation sub group descriptions

Tags: discussion, design

I selected "Not pr0gromming related" etc from Area 51 because I wanted to avoid asking a question that would be choked by aggrandizing badge polishing S.E. police and ended up here... 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

and webpage heading of just "programmers"

Do you see anything about "Not programming related" in either the url or the webpage title?

This merely lays the contributor (UGC) open for more discussion closings.

your very website design is typical geek..or greek whichever.....

Comment: There's a big notice over the name in the [site's A51 proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related): "Note that the scope and purpose of this proposal changed DRASTICALLY during the beta. **Along with the name.** Please refer to the Programmers FAQ for the current definition." Not sure what more we can do to let people know the site's scope and name has changed.

Comment: I apologize if it was there when I visited. I recall looking at that page three times.